# 'ambiguous type' error when defining a union of types having type inclusions

Tags: ballerina, union-types, ballerina-swan-lake

I have a record named `GenericPet` with several fields. Another record named `Dog` is a type inclusion of the record `GenericPet` and also has its own field `isTrained`. The type `Pet` is a type union of both `GenericPet` and `Dog`. When I try to define an instance of `Pet` in the following code segment, it throws the error: "ambiguous type".

```php
type GenericPet record {
    string name;
    int age;
    string breed;
};

type Dog record {
    *GenericPet;
    boolean isTrained;
};

type Pet GenericPet|Dog;

public function main() {
    Pet myPet = {
        name: "Mickey",
        age: 2,
        breed: "Dane",
        isTrained: false
    };
}
```

Is this behavior expected, and if so, why? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Because `GenericPet` is an open record, the mapping value with the specified four fields is also valid for `GenericPet` (in addition to `Dog`). Therefore, the exact inherent type to use cannot be determined, leading to the "ambiguous type" error.

If you want to resolve this ambiguity, you have a couple of options:

1. **Use Closed Records:**
   If `GenericPet` was a closed record, you would no longer observe the error. You can make `GenericPet` a closed record using the closed record syntax:

   ```php
   type GenericPet record {|
       string name;
       int age;
       string breed;
   |};
   ```
2. **Specify Type Using Type Cast Expression:**
   Alternatively, you can specify the type to use as the inherent type using a type cast expression with the mapping constructor:

   ```php
   Pet pet = <Dog> {
       name: "Mikey",
       age: 2,
       breed: "Dane",
       isTrained: false
   };
   ```